# How to define the type of a function in TypeScript that sorts an array of objects on one property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I wrote a simple function in TypeScript that sorts an array of objects based on one of their property.
The code looks like:

```
export const mySortFunction = (sortKey: string, invert: boolean) => {
  return (a: any, b: any) => {
    if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
      return invert ? 1 : -1;
    } else if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
      return invert ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Then, if I have a type `Person`, with `name` and `lastname` properties, I can sort the list of persons with a call like `persons.sort(mySortFunction('name', true))` or `persons.sort(mySortFunction('lastname', false))`.

The function is working, but I'm not really happy with the typing here.
Basically, I want to have something like:

```
export const mySortFunction = <T>(sortKey: string, invert: boolean) => {
  return (a: T, b: T) => {
    ...
  }
}
```

and indicates to TypeScript that `T` should extends a type that has a key which matches the value of `sortKey`...

How can I set a good typing for my function signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyof`: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYE8DK0YBiArsgjAJYpwC8cAPACoB8AFKvgNLBYBccA1twgAzOAwA0ccsgBuwWHwBGECABtgAQ2QBKGkzgBvAFBxTcKMBhEoyOCw18JcRY93V9xs16mj7AbXZYLiwAXXpnAM5uEN1Pb3iLKxspWXl4AH44AEY4PgBaLIBuE3i4AF84YFVUYB87DUig6Lh9RUaYYJjDEtKzROtbaTlYOEyC3Ozi3rKe737kgAYpszLi1aMjGCwwWoAFeXZbWjjTZA0MYD50KGkAc2XTVQ10M4urmBvke6N1oyQ0eA7KCHVB8fbAlB+MK0PyzAxwV6XOAAciyyMkTxe5yRqOR5XEcIR2L4yIATOi4JiYIiSeT8UYQsUjECQQA6QIwFjYPCwYikCgoFjIqmIikfIjAbTaQpAA)

```
export const mySortFunction = <T>(sortKey: keyof T, invert: boolean) => {
    return (a: T, b: T) => {
        if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
            return invert ? 1 : -1;
        } else if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
            return invert ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return 0;
    };
};

type Person = {
    name: string;
    lastname: string;
};

const persons: Person[] = [
    { name: '1', lastname: '1' },
    { name: '2', lastname: '2' },
];

persons.sort(mySortFunction('lastname', true)); // OK
persons.sort(mySortFunction('test', true)); // Argument of type '"test"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"lastname" | "name"'
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew that the solution was quite simple indeed.